# Does "int (*)[]" decay into "int **" in a function parameter?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, language-lawyer

I posted this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269648/int-vs-int-n-vs-int-n-in-functions-parameters-which-one-do-you-think-i/269660?noredirect=1#comment549439_269660) on programmers.stackexchange earlier today. I have always assumed that `int (*)[]` does **not** decay into `int **` in function parameters but I got multiple responses to my question that suggested that it does.

I have used `int (*)[]` heavily in my function parameters but now I have become really confused.

When I compile this function using `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall`

```
void function(int (*a)[])
{
    sizeof(*a);
}
```

I get this error message:

```
c99 -Wall -pedantic -c main.c -o main.o
main.c: In function ‘function’:
main.c:3:11: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘int[]’ 
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Which suggests that `*a` has the type `int []` and not `int *`.

Can someone explain if things like `int (*)[]` decays into `int **` in function parameters and give me some reference (from the standard documents perhaps) that proves why it is so.

Comment: I don't think so, but I am not sure.

Comment: No. Only arrays and functions decay. Pointers don't decay.

Comment: (Interestingly, `T(*)[]` is an incomplete type that can never be completed, unlike just `T[]`.)

Comment: Of course `int (*)[]` doesn't get adjusted. It's neither an array type nor a function type.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Are you sure? `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` accepts `int (*foo)[]; int (*foo)[42];`, where the second declaration completes the former, doesn't it?

Comment: @alk I do not call `function()`. I can not do that because it does not compile. It is just an example to show why I do not think that it decays.

Comment: @mafso: Hm, I was thinking of C++ 3.9/6, "The type of a pointer to array of unknown size cannot be completed.". But maybe C is different!

Comment: @KerrekSB: This is C, not C++, maybe they differ here. `g++` doesn't accept my TU from the last comment, saying the types are incompatible. FWIW, I wasn't correct in my last comment. A pointer to an incomplete type is always a complete type (in C). But nonetheless, `int (*)[]` and `int (*)[42]` are compatible in C. (Btw, the only gotcha with pointers to incomplete array types I know of is that `*a[0]` is invalid while `**a` is fine.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ah, hadn't seen your edit. Yes, it's just a C/C++ difference, apparently.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but I'm curious as to why the usage "int (*a)[]", rather than "int *a []".  I don't think I've ever seen it before.  Is it expected to do something differently, or is it just style?

Comment: @jamesqf: `int (*a)[]` means that `a` is a pointer to an array of `int` on the other hand `int *a[]` means that `a` is an array of pointers to `int`.

Comment: @elias: Thanks.  Though now I wonder about the difference between that and just 'int *a' (having malloced a to point to something, of course).

Comment: @jamesqf: There is not much difference. The only differences are that `int (*)[]` must point to an array and cannot point to an regular `int` and that `int (*a)[]` gets indexed using `(*a)[0]` while `int *a` gets indexed using `a[0]`. The question I linked in this question has an example of the difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only array types converted to pointer to its first element when passed to a function. `a` is of type *pointer to an array of `int`*, i.e, **it is of pointer type and therefore no conversion**.

For the prototype

```
void foo(int a[][10]);
```

compiler interpret it as

```
void foo(int (*a)[10]);
```

that's because `a[]` is of array type. `int a[][10]` will never be converted to `int **a`. That said, the second para in that [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/269660) is wrong and misleading.

As a function parameter, `int *a[]` is equivalent to `int **` this is because `a` is of *array* type .

Comment: Perhaps your answer got downvoted because it's the *array* that decays not the "*array name*"? However: It wasn't me! <tm G.Th.>

Comment: @alk; *Decay* is not mentioned anywhere in C standard.

Comment: Does the Standard really use "convert"?

Comment: @alk; Yes. If you interested then I will post some quote from standard.

Comment: Quoting the Standard always is a good idea. However didn't T.C: already did that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27878746/694576

Comment: @alk; **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**: *When used in the
expression `x[i][j]`, that array is in turn converted to a pointer to the first of the `int`s, so `x[i][j]`
yields an `int`.* At the same time, there is nothing like `decay` used in standard in this context.

Comment: *Convert* is for values, not types. In a function's parameter list, the word is *adjusted*.

Answer (score 7):

`int (*)[]` is a pointer to an array of `int`.

In your example, `*a` *can* decay to `int*`. But `sizeof(*a)` doesn't do decaying; it is essentially `sizeof(int[])` which is not valid.

`a` can not decay at all (it's a pointer).

Comment: You can force it to decay: `sizeof( ( 0 , *a ) )` and get the size of an int pointer.

Answer (score 7):

N1256 §6.7.5.3/p7-8

> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. If the keyword
>   `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type
>   derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
>   corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
>   element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
>   size expression.
>
> 8 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning *type*’’ shall
>   be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning *type*’’, as in
>   6.3.2.1.

`int (*)[]` is "pointer to array of `int`". Is it "array of *type*"? No, it's a pointer. Is it "function returning *type*"? No, it's a pointer. Therefore it does not get adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `int (*a)[]`, `sizeof *a` does not work for one reason: there is no element count for the array. Without an element count, the size cannot be calculated.

As a consequence of this, any pointer arithmetic on `a` will not work because it is defined in terms of the size of an object. Since the size is indeterminate for the array, you cannot use pointer arithmetic on the pointer itself. Array notation is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic, so `sizeof a[0][0]` (or any expression involving `a[n]` won't work whereas `sizeof (*a)[0]` will.

This effectively means you can do very little with the pointer. The only things allowed are:

- dereferencing the pointer using the unary `*` operator
- passing the pointer to another function (the type of the function parameter must be an array of arrays or a pointer to an array)
- getting the size of the pointer (and alignment or type, if your compiler supports either or both of them)
- assigning the pointer to a compatible type

If your compiler supports variable-length arrays (VLAs), and you know the size, you could work around the issue by simply adding a line at the start of the function body as in

```
void
foo (int (*a0)[], size_t m, size_t n)
{
  int (*a)[n] = a0;
  ...
}
```

Without VLAs, you must resort to some other measure.

It is worth noting that dynamic allocation isn't a factor with `int (*)[]`. An array of arrays decays to a pointer to an array (like we have here), so they are interchangeable when passing them to a function (`sizeof` and any `_Alignof` or `typeof` keywords are operators, not functions). This means that the array pointed to must be statically allocated: once an array decays to a pointer, no more decay occurs, so you can't say a pointer to an array (`int (*)[]`) is the same as a pointer to a pointer (`int **`). Otherwise your compiler would happily let you pass `int [3][3]` to a function that accepts `int **` instead of wanting a parameter of the form `int (*)[]`, `int (*)[n]`, `int [][n]`, or `int [m][n]`.

Consequently, even if your compiler doesn't support VLAs, you can use the fact that a statically allocated array has all of its elements grouped together:

```
void foo (int (*a0)[], size_t m, size_t n)
{
  int *a = *a0;
  size_t i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
          // Do something with `a[i * n + j]`, which is `a0[i][j]`.
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

A dynamically allocated one-dimensional array that is used as a two-dimensional array has the same properties, so this still works. It is only when the second dimension is dynamically allocated, meaning a loop like `for (i = 0; i < m; i++) a[i] = malloc (n * sizeof *a[i]);` to allocate each sub-array individually, that this principle not work. This is because you have an array of pointers (`int *[]`, or `int **` after array decay), which point to the first element of an array at another location in memory, rather than an array of arrays, which keeps all of the items together.

So:

- no, `int (*p)[]` and `int **q` cannot be used in the same way. `p` is a pointer to an array, which means all items are grouped together starting the address stored in `p`. `q` is a pointer to a pointer, which means the items may be scattered at different addresses that are stored in `q[0]`, `q[1]`, ..., `q[m - 1]`.
- `sizeof *p` doesn't work because `p` points to an array with an unknown number of elements. The compiler cannot calculate the size of each element, so operations on `p` itself are very limited.